# Agora Broadcast Streaming how to get caption i am working on react native?

Tags: react-native, agora.io, agora, agora-implementation

i want to implement caption in Broadcast Streaming in react-native i am using agora for Broadcast Streaming.

i have read all methods but i has not able to find the desired solution if anyone has any idea please let me know.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.